# Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT multiple values in Android

Tags: android, arrays, email, android-intent

I want to display multiple values in the text message body, however the following code below display no body message even when the textArray has values. Is there any way of adding values to a body of an email through a loop?

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Example");

            int sizeOfArray = list.size();
            String textArray [] = new String[sizeOfArray];

            for(int i = 0;sizeOfArray > i;i++)
            {
                HashMap<String, String> arrayString = list.get(i);
                String user = arrayString.get("user");
                String book = arrayString.get("book");
                textArray[i] = user + " - " + book;
            }

            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textArray);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to get proper documentation on what Intent Receivers are expecting as extra values, but I'm pretty sure you need to pass a `String` and not a `String[]` to putExtra, since the Receiver will anyway end up converting the value to a `String`, so better to control that.

Thats being said, your implementation of the loop is weird. Do you really have a list of `HashMap<String, String>`as input ?

I would do :

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for(HashMap<String, String> item: list){
    String user = item.get("user");
    String book = item.get("book");
    sb.append(user + " - " + book+", ");
}
String value = sb.substring(0, Math.max(0,sb.length()-2));
```

Comment: It is possible to add end of paragraph in each statement, so the values come out at each line instead of togther?

Comment: You can also use "\n" as the separator if you want new lines characters.

Answer (score 1):

Intent.EXTRA_TEXT expects CharSequence according to the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_TEXT

I would guess as you are passing in an array, the receiving activity doesn't know what to do with it and just skips over it.

Trying joining your array values and passing them in as a String.

```
String arg = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join (textArray, '\n');
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, arg);
```

Comment: Where did you get org.apache.commons.lang from please? didn't appear to be in my project

Comment: It's the apache commens lang: http://commons.apache.org/lang/, I just used it as an example, there are other ways of joining an array here: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/91

Comment: Joiner in [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) is also a very nice alternative. You can download a jar file here : http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/